# DynamoDB: Scan on multiple non key attribute

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I am migrating my app from mysql to DynamoDB, I have a table where i match 5 non key attribute  based on certain conditions. This table will have lots of read operations(scan)

Question:Is there are any possible ways that i design a table in such a way that i don't have to scan the table

Any Light on the path would be helpful.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the recently announced [Global Secondary Indexes](http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2013/12/now-available-global-secondary-indexes-for-amazon-dynamodb.html) is what you need.

As with Local Secondary Indexes - you can't you have than one index when querying.

This means you will probably have to move some of that logic into the application layer.